# Why I see only part of the image in the button?

Tags: java, image, jbutton

I add an image to the button in the following way:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("images/col.jpg");
tmp = new JButton(icon);
```

My image is a red sphere but in my button I see only read color. I assume that I see just a small part of the sphere. How can I see the whole image in the button?

**ADDED**

Yes, my icon is bigger than the button. Is there a simple way to force the icon to fit the size of the button?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the icon is bigger than the button? You could try to downscale the image by first loading an `Image` and then calling `Image.getScaledInstance()`.

Edit: Of course the even simpler way is to resize the original file.

Answer (score 0):

You could add some screenshot to clear things a little more.

Some quick first thoughts:

- your image is larger than the icon space in the button
- try to modify the button border and/or insets
- keep in mind that different themes might show different results